# CoordinatorLayout with ViewPager that contains WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager, fragment

I have the following XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="socialcenterapp.com.user.myapp.activities.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="24dp" android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon_fab"
        app:backgroundTint="#b3c8ff"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

inside the ViewPager I have Fragment that contains WebView.
I want that when the user scrolling down in the WebView the TabLayout is disappear and back in scrolling up.
How can I do it?

The Fragment XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="myapp.com.user.myapp.fragments.MyFragment">


<WebView>
    <android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android:id="@+id/webView">
    <android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I am facing with this issue aswell

Answer (score 2):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```